# Core Data Transform iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

I am developing a sample application with core data with  a entity which has two attribute-ID and name.For ID I have set  the data type as transformable .After a value for ID is stored in database,Can I pull the transformed ID from the DB and get back the ID?(Not Through the code, by opening the DB in SQLite manager and pulling out from the ID column).Is there a way to check what is stored in DB manually without executing  code? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the DB from the device to your machine. I use [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) to do this.  The best way to view/edit the DB from there is [Base](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/base/id402383384?mt=12), but Firefox has a FREE plugin called [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/).

Comment: Thanks Jeff I have used iExplorer and SQLite manager,but the transformable data stored in db is not in clear text.Is there a way to convert the transformable data to clear text.

Comment: @divya Why in the world would you need to use Transform types for things like "ID"?  If you make them regular datatypes you will be able to see them as you please.

Comment: @borrrden I am trying to store it securely using transforms and looking if there are ways where a hacker can break it.

Comment: Here's an open-source library for creating an encrypted data store:
https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data

This would probably be easier to manage than using transforms and baking your own crypto scheme. Hope it helps.